# Can I invoke a protractor test from another protractor test

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

I have several protractor tests completed, and the test I'm working on now requires actions on a previous page. I need to create an item on page A before testing the functionality on page B. I have a test to create an item on page A, and I'm wondering if I can call that protractor test as part of the test setup for page B.

I'm using the page object pattern, and I understand I can copy the relevant code into the test for page B, but I would rather just call the previous test while running the test for page B.

Comment: Per best practices for testing, it is not recommended to make tests that depend on other tests. Each should be able to run on its own. You should make a function to create the item and re-use that function in both tests. If that means the second test completely overlaps the first test, then it means you only need one test.

Comment: I agree, and my unit tests and integration tests are atomic. User Journeys can be atomic, but the tests within a journey may not be. For maintainability many journeys are broken down into sub-tests and these typically run in a specific order with some dependencies. Since I don't have a common point for these 2 journeys, I guess I can put the common function in the params object that is global for all protractor tests. Thanks for the comment!